# Ruby - Setter methods for hash properties

Tags: ruby, oop, hash, setter

I've been tooling around with Ruby by converting a pen and paper RPG to a script.

Right now I have a character's stats kept in a hash, which I would like to be able to set via public method.  I got that working with:

```
class Character
    attr_reader :str, :con, :dex, :wis, :int, :level, :mods, :stats
    def initialize str, con, dex, wis, int, cha, level = 1
        @stats = { :str => str, :con => con, :dex => dex, :wis => wis, :int => int, :cha => cha }
        @mods = {}
        @level = level

        @stats.each_pair do |key, value|
            @mods[key] = ((value / 2 ) -5).floor
        end
    end

    def []=(index, value)
        @stats[index] = value
    end
end
```

This allows me to instantiate a new character, then update `@stats` by running `newChar.stats[:str] = 12`

However, I also seem to be able to modify the `@mods` using this method as well, which is undesirable.  `newChar.mods[:str] = 15` will successfully alter the `@mods` hash, which from my understanding should not be possible with the current setter method.

On a slightly separate note, the iterator I'm using to create my `@mods` hash seems clunky but I haven't found anything better to accomplish the task.

Comment: To generate `mods`, I think you want `@mods = Hash[@stats.map {|k,v| [k, (v / 2 - 5).floor] }]

Comment: @Chuck awesome, thank you.  I looked for a map method in `http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html` but did not see one.  

What exactly is that construct that you wrapped the whole thing in?  The Hash[...]

Comment: Ahhh, nevermind, I see now.  I didn't find it in the Hash documentation because it's part of the included Enumerable module.

Comment: The `Hash[]` is the `[]` method of the Hash class, which creates a hash out of either the argument list (if you provide multiple arguments) or the passed array (if you pass an array, like we're doing here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not even call your `[]=` method in your example. This would be done like so:

```
newChar[:str] = 123
```

instead of

```
newChar.stats[:str] = 123
```

so to call `newChar.stats[:str] = 123` you do not even need you method definition. The reason is that `newChar.stats` as well as `newChar.mods` will both return the actual hash which can then be altered.

One possible workaround is to freeze the `@mods` variable so it can't be altered any more:

```
def initialize str, con, dex, wis, int, cha, level = 1
    # omitted ...

    @stats.each_pair do |key, value|
        @mods[key] = ((value / 2 ) -5).floor
    end

    @mods.freeze
end
```

This is a good solution if you never want to be able to change `@mods` again. Trying to set a value will result in an error:

```
newChar.mods[:con] = 123
# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash
```

Inside your class, you can, however, overwrite `@mods` entirely.

To summarize, the full class would be:

```
class Character
    attr_reader :str, :con, :dex, :wis, :int, :level, :mods, :stats
    def initialize str, con, dex, wis, int, cha, level = 1
        @stats = { :str => str, :con => con, :dex => dex, :wis => wis, :int => int, :cha => cha }
        @mods = {}
        @level = level

        @stats.each_pair do |key, value|
            @mods[key] = ((value / 2 ) -5).floor
        end

        @mods.freeze
    end
end
```

Comment: The freeze method looks promising, thank you.

I guess what I'm confused about then is why I can `newChar.stats[:str] = 12` without any sort of setter method present.  Shouldn't I not have access to a property unless a setter method is defined?

I also notice that if I remove `:stats` from attr_reader, I can no longer set the property as well, which may be because, as you said, it will no longer return the hash for me to operate on.

Comment: @NickBrown: `newChar.stats` returns the value stored in `@stats`, which is just a Hash. It doesn't return some special "property" — it just returns the Hash that was stored in the `@stats` instance variable. Hash already has a `[]=` method, which is how you normally put things in a Hash.

Comment: Well think of it like that: You cannot set the hash itself, but that does not mean that you cannot call methods on the hash. Now the `Hash` class happens to implement a method `[]=` which lets you set values on the hash.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a public getter for a hash but you don't want the user to modify the hash –*the instance-variable of your class*–, you can do it with dup.

```
class MyClass
  ....
  def my_hash
    @my_hash.dup
  end
end
```

Where the solution with `freeze`, as mentioned above, will freeze the hash even for your class, the .dup-solution will let you modify the hash from within your class but not from outside.